# How can I create image of google chart in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-visualization

I was looking for some ready code so I could insert my data, labels etc. into a function and receive a ready google-chart like this.

[image]

But I didn't find any. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mean time, I wrote a function that receive all the necessary parameters, creates a google chart and converts it `UIImage`. Here it is:

> -(UIImage *)produceGoogleChartImage:(NSString*)title
>
> ```
>                            xAxis:(NSArray*)axisXLabels
>                           yAxis:(NSArray*)axisYLabels
>                         andData:(NSArray*)dataValues
>                           color:(NSString*)lineColor
>                      chartWidth:(NSNumber*)width
>                      chartHight:(NSNumber*)hight
>                     lagendLabel:(NSString*)legend
>                        minScale:(NSNumber*)minScale
>                        maxScale:(NSNumber*)maxScale{
>
> NSMutableString *myurl = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chxl=0:|"];
>
>
> //axisXLabels
> int countAxisXLabels = [axisXLabels count];
>
> for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < countAxisXLabels; ++i)
> {
>     NSNumber *value = [axisXLabels objectAtIndex:i];
>     [myurl appendFormat:@"%@", value];
>     if(i < countAxisXLabels - 1)
>         [myurl appendString:@"|"];
> }
>
> [myurl appendString:@"|1:|"];
>
>
> //axisYLabels
>  int countAxisYLabels = [axisYLabels count];
> for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < countAxisYLabels; ++i)
> {
>     NSNumber *value = [axisYLabels objectAtIndex:i];
>     [myurl appendFormat:@"%@", value];
>     if(i < countAxisYLabels - 1)
>         [myurl appendString:@"|"];
> }
>
> [myurl appendString:@"&chxr=0,0,105|1,3.333,100&chxt=x,y&chs="];
>
> //size
> [myurl appendFormat:@"%@x%@&cht=lc&chd=t:", width,hight];
>
> //dataValues
> int countDataValues = [dataValues count];
>
> for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < countDataValues; ++i)
> {
>     NSNumber *value = [dataValues objectAtIndex:i];
>     [myurl appendFormat:@"%@", value];
>     if(i < countDataValues - 1)
>     [myurl appendString:@","];
> }
>
> //legend
> [myurl appendFormat:@"&chdl=%@&chg=25,50&chls=2&",legend];
>
> //color
> [myurl appendFormat:@"chm=o,%@,0,-2,8&chco=%@",lineColor,lineColor];
>
> //title
> [myurl appendFormat:@"&chtt=+%@",title];
>
> //scale
> [myurl appendFormat:@"&chds=%@,%@",minScale,maxScale];
>
>
>
> NSString *theurl=[myurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>
> NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theurl]
> ```
>
> cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
>                                                           timeoutInterval:60.0];
>
> ```
> NSURLResponse* response;
> NSError* error;
> NSData *imageData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response
> ```
>
> error:&error];
>       NSLog(@"%@",error);
>       NSLog(@"%@",response);
>       NSLog(@"%@",imageData);
>
> ```
> UIImage *myimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
>
>
> return myimage;
>
> // Chart Wizard: https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard
>  }
> ```

And here is the test function:

> -(void)test{
>
> ```
> NSString* title = @"Height History";
> NSArray *axisXLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>                        @"Jan",
>                        @"Feb",
>                        @"Mar",
>                        @"Jun",
>                        @"Jul",
>                        @"Aug",
>                        nil];
>
>
> NSArray *axisYLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
>                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
>                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:150],
>                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:200],
>                         nil];
>
> NSArray *dataValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:130],
>                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:140],
>                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:140],
>                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:150],
>                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:170],
>                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:180],
>                        nil];
>
> NSString *lineColor = @"FF9900";
>
> NSNumber *width = [NSNumber numberWithInt:300];
>
> NSNumber *hight = [NSNumber numberWithInt:200];
>
> NSNumber *minScale = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
>
> NSNumber *maxScale = [NSNumber numberWithInt:200];
>
> NSString *legendLabel = @"cm";
>
> UIImage *myimage =[self produceGoogleChartImage:title xAxis:axisXLabels yAxis:axisYLabels andData:dataValues color:lineColor
> ```
>
> chartWidth:width chartHight:hight lagendLabel:legendLabel
>   minScale:minScale maxScale:maxScale];
>
> ```
> _chartImage.image=myimage;
> ```
>
> }

You should get image, like the one in the question.